# Animation gets stuck at the end in Unity Animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am not good at animating in 3D so I have a slight problem. I am making a swinging animation with a bat. Every animation works perfectly fine, but what's the problem here is that when from idle animation goes to swing animation it gets stuck, I have to click few times to return to idle state.
[here is the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4iKA.png)

and

[Here is where the thing gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTQgd.png)

Here you can check the inspector for these two trainsitions:

[from idle to swing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eMIB.png)
[from swing to idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRn55.png)

I am trying to solve this problem for some time now and still don't get it why it's happening.
Here you can check out the code for this. This script is specifically for melee weapons but I think it can apply to other items as well. Everything in the code works except this animator part.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class melee : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float dmg;
    public float range;
    
    private Animator anim;
    private bool attacking = false;
    
    public Camera cam;

    void Start(){
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }



    void FixedUpdate(){
        AnimatorStateInfo info = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
            Attack();
            
        }else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1")){
            anim.SetBool("attacking", false);
        }

    }

    void Attack(){
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, range)){
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            enemyHealth enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<enemyHealth>();
            
            if(enemy != null){
                enemy.TakeDmg(dmg);
            }

        }


        anim.SetBool("attacking", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is your input goes in first if and never gets to second if or overwritten again by the first if.

So you are always making boolean TRUE.

Also i don't think you need a fixedupdate. Regual update should work better.

Answer (score 0):

FixedUpdate() are called more times in a frame to guarantee the most precise Physic Computation. So yeah, how Xentios said

> So you are always making boolean TRUE.
> Also i don't think you need a fixedupdate. Regual update should work better.

you are changing the boolean value too fast. You can set the flag to FALSE after the animation end. Maybe you can speedup the animation if the attack are not hitting anyone.